# QGIS: Values in the wrong columns after a refactor field

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, expression

Currently I am still in the process of building a model with a refactor field algorithm. Even though I have perfectly set up how to convert my data into the right expression however the data's is getting in the WRONG column.
Here is a screenshot about how the date looks like.

[image]

Keep in mind I am keeping the columns the same name and here are the formula's.

[image]

Nothing seems off so far but when I open the new made layer....

[image]

As you noticed the value's are not in the right column, even though the formula is correct? What is going on here?

Edit 2: For now I got around this by Splitting my table of the shapefile up into multiple pieces, then make those pieces go through the each seperate process. And then rejoining them by attribute based on a primary key. established in the beginning. So for now the cause seems to be that are just too many columns in the shapefile. Why this is, someone should explain it to me.

Comment: Did you try `map_get(json_to_map('{"qgis":"rocks"}'), 'qgis')` to avoid using the `case when then when then else end`? Quite unrelated but we never know :)

Comment: Uhm not really it is from gjson but what kind of command is that? Does it translate a GeoJSON easier or something? Because first time I have heard of it.